# Why isn't this Rails post create a record? What's wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

My javascript frontend is posting the following form data:

```
contact[name]:asdas asddas
contact[email]:asdadssa@adsdas.com
contact[message]:asd asd asd asd asd
```

Rails logs show:

```
Started POST "/contacts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-10-27 12:58:06 -0700
Processing by ContactsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"contact"=>{"name"=>"asdsad asads", "email"=>"asas@asdas.com", "message"=>"asd asd asd"}}
```

My Rails controller:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
  end


private
  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :message)
  end

end
```

This is erring with:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: can you paste the full error stack?

Comment: There is no code in your controller to actually save the record.  Something like this https://github.com/rockwellwindsor/ecommerce/blob/master/app/controllers/products_controller.rb#L25

Answer (score 1):

You forgot write the following line after @contact variable:

```
@contact.save
```

Put this and try again